# EPPLUS how to find data using the find command

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am coding an application in C# .NET 4.0 using EPPLUS and trying to load a huge 20mb excel file. I want to find particular strings in the sheet using the Find or Findall method. Can anyone please share a snippet of how to do this because there is no info about this on the internet.

I want to avoid reading all the cells since it takes a lot of time. I want to find that particular string and just copy that specific row without reading the entire sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? And where are the Find/FindAll methods? I can't see them..

Comment: its in the data validation class. I used a simple for loop instead to get my work done

Answer (score 8):

The Find and FindAll methods on ExcelDataValidationCollection are not for searching strings in workbooks/worksheets - instead they will let your search for a specific Data Validation in the worksheet using a lambda expression.

Linq will probably be the best way if you want to query your worksheet for matching value. You can specify a range in the query so that you dont have to loop through the entire sheet. This example is from Sample 8 in EPPlus Samples that can be downloaded on codeplex.

```
//Here we use more than one column in the where clause. We start by searching column D, then use the Offset method to check the value of column C.
            var query3 = (from cell in sheet.Cells["d:d"]
                          where cell.Value is double && 
                                (double)cell.Value >= 9500 && (double)cell.Value <= 10000 && 
                                cell.Offset(0, -1).GetValue<DateTime>().Year == DateTime.Today.Year+1 
                          select cell);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Print all cells with a value between 9500 and 10000 in column D and the year of Column C is {0} ...", DateTime.Today.Year + 1);
            Console.WriteLine();    

            count = 0;
            foreach (var cell in query3)    //The cells returned here will all be in column D, since that is the address in the indexer. Use the Offset method to print any other cells from the same row.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cell {0} has value {1:N0} Date is {2:d}", cell.Address, cell.Value, cell.Offset(0, -1).GetValue<DateTime>());
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: i'm getting issue for executing the below
 foreach (string cellString in ExcelCellDeleteList)
                {
                    var query3 = (from cell in ws.Cells["b:b"] where cell.Value is string select cell);
                }

i want to search the "cellString" string.